# Debug step by step the connect by level code | Oracle 19c |

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I am trying to solve the queries on `hacker rank`

I came across below query not getting what it is doing actually

**Can someone explain me step by step each line of below query**

**Input :**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ1rX.png]

**Query :**

```
SELECT
    N,
    CASE
        WHEN P IS NULL THEN 'Root'
        WHEN CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1 THEN 'Leaf'
        ELSE 'Inner'
    END AS RESULT
FROM
    BINARY_TREE
START WITH
    P IS NULL
CONNECT BY
    P = PRIOR N;
```

**Output of above query :**

[image: Output]

Proper explanation will be appreciated

I wanted to know the `connect by level` what it actually does and usage of it. And how the above query is internally executed and returning output

Comment: Oracle has fine documentation.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns001.htm   `CONNECT BY` turns this into a binary tree.  `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` is true if this row has no children.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html#GUID-0118DF1D-B9A9-41EB-8556-C6E7D6A5A84E

Comment: "debug" means there is a bug in the code. Unless you changed the code I gave you in your other thread, there should be no bug in it. By the way, "I came across below query" is pretty asinine. Good luck getting help in the future, if you continue like that.

Comment: I don't see `connect by level` in the query. You can however use any Boolean expression after `connect by` and it is evaluated for each row.